# Android-support-v4 library doesn't have JobIntentService in B4A

Tags: android, basic4android

I have a library and it depends on `Android-support-v4` (The `JobIntentService` class). I'm going to use it in Basic4Android.

There are two ways of adding `supprt-v4` dependency to project:

- Add 
  `<dependsOn>com.android.support:support-v4</dependsOn>` 
  to library xml.
- Add

```
dependsOn>support-annotations</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-compat</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-v4</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-core-ui</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-core-utils</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-fragment</dependsOn>
<dependsOn>support-media-compat</dependsOn>
```

to that xml.

If I use the first way, I can't find `JobIntentService`. If I use the second way it's fine, but It will have a conflict with the AppCompat library.

So how an I have a complete code of support-v4 without experiencing conflicts?

I know that `JobIntentService` exists in `support-compat` part of android-support-v4, but adding it beside `com.android.support:support-v4` still causes duplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the first way uses **Maven artifacts** to get your library from *Jcenter*, **it might download an old version that does not include this class** in it's class path.

To resolve this clear libraries of B4A placed in the sdk `m2repository`
 folder named `b4a_remote`, delete it and let the B4A redownload the files. Therefore it will download fresh and updated libraries that contain this class.